# TLA+: specify that the range of each element of a sequence of functions is {0}

Tags: tla+

I am trying to specify a collection of memory cells in TLA+, each holding 256 32-bit integers. I would like to specify that at initialization time all the memory is zeroed out. I intuit that the correct approach is something like nested forall statements, but I don't know how to express that in TLA+.

```
---------------------------- MODULE combinators ----------------------------

EXTENDS Integers, FiniteSets, Sequences

CONSTANTS Keys, Values

VARIABLES Cells

TypeOK ==
    /\ Channels = 0 .. 255
    /\ Values = -2147483648 .. 2147483647
    /\ Cells \in Seq([Keys -> Values])

Init == ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1. If `Values` are constants, specify their domain in an `ASSUME`, not in an invariant. `CONSTANT` means some arbitray input; if you meant actual constants, then just define `Values == -2147483648 .. 2147483647`.
2. `Keys` could even be infinite; you must always specify an `ASSUME` for each constant (even `IsFiniteSet`).
3. You didn't declare `Channels`, but, like `Values` it seems like it should be a simple definition, not an invariant.
4. You didn't say how many `Cells` you're starting out with. The `TypeOK` is defined, the number of `Cells` can change at each step, and even be empty.

But suppose you want N cells for some N, so:

`Cells = [c ∈ 1..N ↦ [k ∈ Keys ↦ 0]]`

But you wrote "domain" and here 0 is in the range, so I'm not sure I understand your question. You also mention channels so perhaps you meant:

`Cells = [c ∈ 1..N ↦ [k ∈ Channels ↦ 0]]`

Comment: The "domain" part was my mistake, I meant range. Thanks for the excellent answer, I'll definitely use this.